# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in export default createNavigatorFactory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm new to react native and I'm having some issues with the navigator component. I am trying to implement a simple stack navigator, where I display a list of items and navigate to a detailed screen of that item once pressed in a certain element. My code, in execution order, is the following:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from './components/MainComponents';

// It just renders the mainComponent
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Main />
    );
  }
}
```

**MainComponents.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';
import DishDetail from './DishDetailComponent';
import { View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator();
class Main extends Component {

  render() {
navigation the app will add a bar with back arrow at the paddingTop
    return (
      <View>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <MenuNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName="Menu">
            <MenuNavigator.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu}  options={{ title: 'Menu' }}/>
            <MenuNavigator.Screen name="DishDetail" component={DishDetail}  options={{ title: 'Dish details' }}/>
          </MenuNavigator.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
  
export default Main;
```

**MenuComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';

class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = { dishes: DISHES};
    }
    static navigationOptions ={
        title: 'Menu'
    }
    
    render() {

    const renderMenuItem = ({item, index}) => {
        return (
                <ListItem
                    key={index}
                    title={item.name}
                    subtitle={item.description}
                    hideChevron={true}  
                    onPress ={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DishDetail', {dishId: item.id})}
                    leftAvatar={{ source: require('./images/alberto.png')}}
                  />
        );
    };

    return (
            <FlatList 
                data={this.state.dishes}
                renderItem={renderMenuItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                />
    );
    }
}
export default Menu;
```

**DishDetailComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';

function RenderDish(props)
{
    const dish =props.dish;

    if (dish != null)
    {
        return(
            <Card
                    featuredTitle={dish.name}
                    image = {require('./images/uthappizza.png')}>
                    <Text style={{margin: 10}}>
                            {dish.description}
                    </Text>
            </Card>
            );
    }
    else{
        return(<View></View>);
    }
}

class DishDetail extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dishes: DISHES
        };
    }
    static navigationOptions ={
        title: 'Dish Details'};

    render(){   
        const dishId = this.props.navigation.getParam('dishId', '');
        return(<RenderDish dish={this.state.dishes[+dishId]} />);
    }
}
export default DishDetail;
```

With this code, I keep getting this error when running my code:
[image]

I have followed several tutorials (as I said, I'm a complete beginner) and have had quite a few version issues, which I think can be part of the problem. My dependencies are the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.0.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.0.1",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-constants": "~9.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-gesture-handler": "^0.0.4",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-video": "^4.4.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2"
  }
```

Comment: You have two versions of navigation installed, remove "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2" these and install the latest of @react-navigation/native which is 5.7.1 i guess, better check it

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! What you said did solve the issue, but it seems like I have another problem in my code, as the screen is displayed for just a few seconds and, then, turns white. Do you have any idea of what could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you see the dish list? Better check the console for any errors

Comment: The list is shown just a moment and then the screen turns white and the console does not show errors, only some warnings: "react-dom.development.js:12338 Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use", "Animated: `useNativeDriver` is not supported because the native animated module is missing. Falling back to JS-based animation. To resolve this, add `RCTAnimation` module to this app, or remove `useNativeDriver`." and "DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map"

Comment: i dont see any problem in the code above, better put some static content and see whether its caused by something else